# Views missing on MySQL database

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL database that was restarted a few hours ago

When it restarted, the views were missing. The tables all seem intact, and a check on the mysql tables seems all good.

Any ideas what could have happened?

Comment: So, `SHOW FULL TABLES` only shows base tables, but not views?

Comment: Please run `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.views;` and `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE ENGINE IS NULL;`. Do you get zeros ???

Comment: Sorry for the wild goose chase.  Speaking of geese, it appears that some goose restored an old backup to our server sans views.

Answer (score 1):

A backup was restored to the server sans views.  Simple really.

Comment: We were using the retired MySQL administrator tool for backups (for transferring data to development machines, specifically).  This tool includes the views as part of the script.  However, when running the script for restore, it must have failed at restoring the views.